# Showing that if a functional $f$ is in the dual space $X'$ if and only if the null space of $f$ is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

I'm supposed to show that for a normed space $X$ then we have that for a functional $f\in X^{*}$ ($X^{*}$ is the algebraic dual space of $X$) we have that

$$f\in X' \Leftrightarrow\ N(f)\text{ is closed}.$$

I've shown the $\Rightarrow$ part of the statement above but I'm having trouble showing the $\Leftarrow$ part. In the exercise it is hinted to show that if $f$ is unbounded then $N(f)$ is not closed.

The hint states that I should consider a sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\subset X$ such that $||x_k||=1$ and $|f(x_k)|\geq k$. Then I should let $x\in X\setminus N(f)$ which just means $f(x)\neq 0$ and then construct a sequence $\{y_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\subset N(f)$ and show that $y_k\rightarrow x$.

I think I see the big picture behind the strategy of the hint but I have no clue as to how I would construct the sequence $\{y_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ in such a way. If anyone can give any hints as to how to construct this sequence that would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $y_k=x-a_kx_k$ where $a_k=\frac {f(x)} {f(x_k)}$. Then $f(y_k)=0$ so $y_k \in N(f)$. Also $|a_k| \leq \frac {|f(x)|} k \to 0$ so $\|y_k -x\|=|a_k|\|x_k\|=|a_k| \to 0$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! So this would then show that the sequence converges to $x$, but as $x$ is not in $N(f)$ that shows $N(f)$ can not be closed. Does this then imply that for $N(f)$ to be closed then $f$ has to be in $X'$?

Comment: @James Yes, we have proved by contradiction that if $N(f)$ is closed then $f \in X'$.

Comment: Is it a proof by contradiction because $N(f)$ is always a closed subspace and since we arrived at the opposite that must imply that the assumption of $f$ being unbounded is false?